# YUI Column Selection

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I'm having issues using YUI's DataTable Column Selection Functionality. I've tried,

`myEndColDataTable.subscribe("theadCellClickEvent", myEndColDataTable.onEventSelectColumn);`

and

`myEndColDataTable.subscribe("cellClickEvent", function (oArgs) {
            this.selectColumn(this.getColumn(oArgs.target));

        });`

The issue is, I have an initial column selected programmatically. I can highlight the other column, but it doesn't remove the selection from the initially-selected column.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - there is no quick clean solution.

YUI DataTable currently (as of 2.8) lacks an `unselectAllColmns` method to match `unselectAllRows` (which is called by `onEventSelectRow`).

It is also worth noting that `onEventSelectColumn` selects the column header, so `unselectAllCells` will not work.

You could implement your own `unselectAllColumns()` function like this:

```
function unselectAllColumns (dataTable) {
        var i, oColumn, oColumnSet = dataTable.getColumnSet();
        for (i=0; i<oColumnSet.keys.length; i++) {
                oColumn = oColumnSet.keys[i];
                if (oColumn.selected) {
                        dataTable.unselectColumn(oColumn);
                }
        }
}
```

This will be marginally more efficient than using `getSelectedColumns()` because you will not need to build an intermediate array of only selected columns (looking at the source getSelectedColumns calls getColumnSet and walks the array just as above).

Comment: I looked at the row select example, and have it working, in a previous step. I tried those methods already, and they work, except for the fact that they don't unselect the previously-selected column when I select a new column. I tried the slight variation you had on your first example too, but it just doesn't work. Next step, I'm now trying to get the column index of the selected column and put it into a div, kind of like <code>document.getElementById('lastColumn').innerHTML=myEndColDataTable.getSelectedColumns();</code> but it returns an array.

Comment: You are correct - looking at the source, the selectColumn() code is only half implemented, when compared to select row. I rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can do this, but its not elegant. There has to be a better way.

```
myEndColDataTable.subscribe("cellClickEvent", function (oArgs) {
    var colUnSelect = myEndColDataTable.getSelectedColumns();
    myEndColDataTable.unselectColumn(colUnSelect[0]);
    myEndColDataTable.selectColumn(myEndColDataTable.getColumn(oArgs.target));  
});
```